# Two-terms Exponential model (2nd order) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, regression, exponential

I need to use the polyfit command to determine the best exponential coefficients for the following 2nd order two-terms equation:

```
y= a1 * exp(b1*x1^2+b2*x2^2+b3*x1*x2+b4*x1+b5*x2)
```

For the simplest situation (`y= a* exp(kx)`) I would proceed like this:

```
yeqn = @(coefs, x) coefs(1).*exp(coefs(2).*x);
        xi  = x;
        eta = log(y);
        P = polyfit(xi, eta, 1);
        MyCoefs(1) = exp(P(2));
        MyCoefs(2) = P(1)
```

Is there any chance to do the same thing for my situation, or should I use another approach?

Comment: @J0e3gan please make sure to correct every issue with posts you edit, like whacky indentation, missing code formatting in text, and arbitrary capitalization in the title. These hurt more than what you're correcting.

Comment: missy your example code is confusing. First `y` seems to be a function handle, but then `eta = log(y);` seems to contradict this. What are your variables? Why is `yeqn` not used anywhere? If you can fit for your first `y` function, why can't you fit for your `yeqn` function the same way?

Comment: For future reference: OP's name was "missy" before deletion, hopefully explains my previous comment.